# jQuery Bounce Makes CSS Buttons Disappear

Tags: jquery, css

I've recently replaced the images of my buttons (where the jQuery code worked just fine) with CSS buttons, and now they're disappearing as soon as I click on them (which activates the bounce function).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KGAmZ

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: good question. Not sure why, but I can confirm that it occurs in the demo in Chrome 15 dev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The margin-top rules are throwing things off. Remove `margin-top` from #mainMenu and replace it with `top: -45px`. Then remove the top rule from .mainMenuButton, and you should be set.

```
#mainMenu
{
    position: relative;
    width: 1024px;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: inherit;
    top: -45px;
    zoom: 1; /* For IE6 */
}
.mainMenuButton
{
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 128px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    behavior: url(js/border-radius.htc);
}
```

**Edit:** I'm new to the fiddle. Example there as well: http://jsfiddle.net/KGAmZ/8/

Comment: Weird, but fantastic! Thanks =D

Comment: Sure! In my experience, jQuery animation gets along nicer with relative positioning than margin and padding values.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the wrong class.

Change it to this and it works

```
$(".mainMenuButtonText").click(function()
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/KGAmZ/2/

**EDIT**

As per your comment below... in that case, just remove `top: -45px;` from the `.mainMenuButton` rule.

Example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/KGAmZ/9/

Comment: I actually want the entire CSS button + text to bounce though =b

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately Matt answered 3 minutes before you according to stackoverflow =( Sorry!!!

Comment: No problem @user889205.  Just trying to help.